# Anyone have an idea for setting a margin on a div outside of the scrollbar when overflow-auto triggers?

Tags: html, css

So I have a tall column div, with a content div, empty space, and an absolute-to-the-bottom div.

When the browser is resized to a short height, I'd like overflow: auto to trigger on the content div. This works fine, but I'm trying to make it be smart with the absolute bottom div, so the scroll bar is always above the bottom div.

I'm using the Gumby framework for column management and styling so my JSFiddle isn't working well, but I'll post pictures to better get across what my problem is.

I can only post two links and no images at my current reputation, so I'll have to only have two. Pretend I have a picture here of the below images working fine at large heights, stretching to a max height and stopping.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nt0o.png
Here's a photomanipulation of what I WANT it to do. The content div needs to end at the top of the absolute div floating on the bottom there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL5Eh.png
But instead, it activates overflow:auto way late, and nothing I've thought of so far will push it higher against the bottom of its container.

---

Edit: Next time I will take the time rebuild a fiddle. A simpler way of phrasing this question would be: Is there a pure CSS way to have an element take 'position: absolute' elements into account when calculating height? I've done more research since posting this, and it appears there is not. As such, I will just be using javascript to modify the height of the top element as [100% - absolute elements]. Thanks for the answer attempts!

---

Edit #2: For an extra hacky CSS3-only solution, height: calc(100% - 100px); worked.

Comment: I've tried adding a margin-bottom to the overflowed div, and a bumper div between the bottom of the container and the overflowed div. I had a hell of a time trying to strip out just this section to post to a fiddle, but getting it to work with the gumby horizontal-responsiveness framework I was using didn't work.

Comment: We need code. This in itself means nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make it simple, keep it all wrapped up, no absolute positioning. The advanced search button option is pushed down by the searches above it. The heights are percentage based and `min-height` prevents the container from getting too small.

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#search-wrap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50%;
  min-height: 200px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  background: #CCC;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
#search-simple {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 80%;
}
#search-advanced a {
  display: block;
  background: #F00;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-wrap">
  <div id="search-simple">
    <ul>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
      <li>Sample</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="search-advanced">
    <a href="#">Advanced Search</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Have a fiddle as well - [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2hsQ/)!

Comment: Thank you for responding, that was much more helpful than the above user. This fiddle almost exactly matches my code, except the height of the 'search-wrap' container is a percentage of the current viewport, has position: relative applied to it, and the advanced search button is absolutely positioned to the bottom. 

I think I am going to close this question, this can be solved fairly simply by changing the hight of the various divs using javascript. I hate to cheat like this, but seems less time-consuming. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, the height can be a percentage in the CSS. I don't see why javascript needs to be used!